# Добавление в массив в Angularjs

Tags: массивы, angularjs, localstorage

```js
myApp.controller('editCtrl', function ($scope, adFactory) {
 $scope.adList = adFactory.ads;
 $scope.insertNewAd = function(){
  adFactory.insertAd($scope.myAd);
 };
 
 console.log($scope.adList)
 
});
```

Помогите с решением проблемы. Не получается добавить объект в массив не изменив старые. Объект как бы добавляется, но при этом перезаписываются все старые сохранённые объекты.

```js
myApp.service('adFactory', function() {
 var self = this;
 this.ads = [];
 
  
 this.insertAd = function(poster){
  
  function getAds(){
   self.ads = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adstorage'));
  };

  self.ads.push({
    id: _.uniqueId(),
    title: poster,
    description: poster
  });  
    
  localStorage.setItem ('adstorage', JSON.stringify(self.ads));
 };

});
```

Comment: Суть проблемы непонятна. Укажите какой результат ожидаелся и какой был получен.

Comment: Ожидалось что по нажатию на кнопку на будет  срабатывать функция по добавлению объекта в массив и сохранение его в localstorage. В результате объект в массив добавляется, но при этом перезаписываются старые объекты, в них сохраняются данные с нового объекта.

Comment: а если воспользоваться *отладкой*: `self.ads = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adstorage'));` после это строчки сделать вывод в консоль содержимого `ads` массив содержит старые данные?

Comment: @ArtyomSapsay выложите воспроизводимый пример с багом, по текущему коду ничего не понятно где он может перезаписывать.

Comment: Выложил в сообщении код контроллера который вызывает функцию добавления данных в массив.

Comment: Вывел после команды self.ads = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adstorage')); в консоль содержимое ads. Все также данные перезаписываются, только ID меняется, а tittle и description меняются.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку, вместо `function(poster)` надо было `function(myAd)`. `myAd` это мой `ng-model="myAd"` который я использую в форме для добавления данных в массив. Всё работает.

```js
this.insertAd = function(myAd){
  
  function getAds(){
   self.ads = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adstorage'));
  };

  self.ads.push({
    id: _.uniqueId(),
    title: myAd.title,
    description: myAd.description
  });  
    
  localStorage.setItem ('adstorage', JSON.stringify(self.ads));
 };
```